# lodash omitBy for nested objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

Trying to use lodash omitBy but its only omitting one level deep. I'm starting to think deep objects are not supported. Anyone know if this is the case and how I would go about omitting empty or null properties in nested objects.

const obj = {
name: "tik",
age: "",
data: {
id: "",
flag: true,
option: "",
}
}

```
const omitted= omitBy(obj, (a) => isEmpty(a));

Output = {  name: 'tik" age: 21, data: { id: "", flag: true, option: "" } }
```

**should be:**

```
Output = {  name: 'tik" data: { flag: true } }
```

Comment: This has not been answered in listed post.

Comment: Change the test to work on the value, and not the keys. `if (key in keysToOmitIndex) {         return; }` => `if (isEmpty(value)) return;`, and remove the redundant code that refers to keys.